# AWS Kinesis Video stream from Android is distorted

Tags: android, video-streaming, codec, amazon-kinesis

I'm using the [AWS Kinesis Video Producer SDK for Android](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams/latest/dg/producer-sdk-android.html) to stream video to my AWS Kinesis Video Stream. However when I view it in the stream console in my AWS account, the video looks out of focus, in greyscale and has a green/purple flickering in the bottom half of the video.

I'm streaming from a [Vuzix Blade smart glasses](https://www.vuzix.com/products/blade-smart-glasses). This is an Android device, SDK Version 22.

I've played around with the `AndroidCameraMediaSourceConfiguration` options, and set the NAL adoption flags to `StreamInfo.NalAdaptationFlags.NAL_ADAPTATION_ANNEXB_CPD_AND_FRAME_NALS` (all other options result in a `InvalidCodecPrivateDataException` or a `'Verify that the stream contains valid H.264 content.'` error in the AWS console when I try to view the video).

Has anyone seen this type of distortion before, and is there any solution for it?

[image: Distorted video from Vuzix Blade on AWS Kinesis Stream console]

Comment: Kevin, I have same issue with you. Did you have solution for this ?

Comment: @gstream79 - no, no solution yet